# Wordpress user_meta per post

Tags: wordpress, data-structures

I have a custom plugin which generates some data PER user PER post.

I am at the point of replacing my hard-coded data used for testing with data brought from, and sent to, the db and wanted some advice.

The data per user will be:

- postID >

  - currentScore
  - totalScore
  - totalSpend
  - timesWon
  - wonTotal

My question is - is the most efficient way of storing this as a meta_key array or as separate fields?

Again this will be for every user for every post so I am worried about bloating the db unnecessarily.

I also don't understand how to assign all of the child variables to the parent variable of postID.

I think I am on the right track with this but don't understand why the 'your-key' is there:

```
$the_meta_array = array (
'postID' => ‘$post->ID’,
   array (
   'currentScore' => 'value-2',
   'totalScore' => 'value-3',
   'totalSpend' => 'value-4',
   'timesWon' => 'value-5',
   'wonTotal' => 'value-6',
));  
$user_id = wp_get_current_user();
$user_meta_key = 'your-key';  
add_user_meta( $user_id, $user_meta_key, $the_meta_array );
```

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you should get the inner array
$the_meta_array = array (
   'currentScore' => 'value-2',
   'totalScore' => 'value-3',
   'totalSpend' => 'value-4',
   'timesWon' => 'value-5',
   'wonTotal' => 'value-6',
); and use the postID as the user_meta_key.
like this: 
add_user_meta($user_id, $post->ID, $the_meta_array)

Is this what you're after?

Comment: I mean if that code works then it sounds like a great solution.  I will give it a try.  Do you see any issues with each user having 100+ meta keys? (one for each postID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will save the array for each based using postID as the meta_key
Kind of like this: 
User
  1301
    currentScore
    totalScore
    ...
  1302
    currentScore
    totalScore
    ...

```
$the_meta_array = array (
   'currentScore' => 'value-2',
   'totalScore' => 'value-3',
   'totalSpend' => 'value-4',
   'timesWon' => 'value-5',
   'wonTotal' => 'value-6',
);  
$user_id = wp_get_current_user();
$user_meta_key = 'userScore' . $post->ID;  
add_user_meta( $user_id, $user_meta_key, $the_meta_array );
```

As suggested by O. Jones, use a distinct prefix for the meta_key (e.g. 'userScore-')

Comment: This is good. One suggestion, make the key more distinct. If you just use a number it may collide with some other plugin's keys. I suggest `$user_meta_key = 'your-key-' . $post->ID;` It will give keys like `your-key-1234` .

Comment: Ok yes this sounds very promising, thanks for taking the time to answer.  I will try it and come back with any issues/amendments.